# Sortable appending to wrong target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable element whose children are also sortable.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/U9k7d/)  demonstrating what I've got so far.

In the fiddle or image below, the blue area is `#container`, white boxes are `.child` and group of such boxes marked with a black border is `.parent`.

`#container` and `.parent` are sortables.

[image: normal]

If an item is dragged and dropped from one `.parent` to another `.parent`, I'm simply appending the item (jQuery ui does this automatically). If an item (`.child`) is dropped into `#container` I'm wrapping it in a `.parent` div to mark it as a new parent.

Now, select prod3 by clicking it, drag it to the left of prod5 till placeholder appears to the left of prod5. drag prod3 down as much as possible while still having the placeholder to the left of prod5, then drop it.

If jQuery UI detects it as a drop inside the `.parent` of prod5, the expected result should look like the following:

[image: expected scenario 1]

If it is detected as a drop in `#container` the expected result should be as follows:

[image: expected scenario 2]

Now what's happening (evident from logs in console): a receive event is triggered on `#container` , even though placeholder was inside `.parent`. I can live with that - but the problem is, even though the `receive` event was fired on `#container`, the dragged item `prod3` is appended to `.parent` and no receive event was triggered on `.parent`!

So due to this strange behavior, since the receive event is triggered on `#container`, the item is wrapped in a `.parent` div, but it's then appended to the `.parent` which contained prod5. Hence I get a `.parent` div inside a `.parent` div as shown in picture below, which should not happen.

[image: error]

Does any one have any idea why this is happening? Or can someone suggest a better way for doing this (sortable items inside a sortable container)?

*Side note: this is a corner case and you might have to try it few times to reproduce this scenario.*

*Update:*
According to this [smaller demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YMnwU/7/), this seems to be a bug with jquery ui, which i reported [here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/10113). A temporary workaround is to manually handle the situation inside `#container`'s receive event as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24245290/2333214). any better solutions are welcome...

Comment: btw, you had spelling mistake in tolerance, which I think automatically sets the tolerance to intersect instead of pointer which you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is very easy

You need to add this condition:

```
if (!ui.item.parent().hasClass('parent')){
     ui.item.wrap(parent).before(helper); 
}
```

I found that additional .parent div appearing only when items parent has class `.parent .ui-sortable` and if it have class just `.ui-sortable` it fully works. So simply add this condition and all works fine.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/U9k7d/9/)

Comment: You're handling the drop in `#container`s receive event... still the `#container`s receive is firing while something is dropped in `.parent`… the fiddle is just a baby sample… ideally this should not happen in the real application… But thanks for the time i might have to do workarounds and handle everything myself as a last resort if this behavior can't be fixed...

Comment: btw for checking whether an element have/don't have a particular class we should use `has class()` otherwise if we add one more class `attr('class')` won't work.. hence updating the ans...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it seems the `.parent` thinks the `.child` is still inside when it isn't. 
A test with bigger borders shows that when the pointer is outside the margin, below the `.parent`, the expected behaviour is that the parent should collapse and the `#container` should accept the `.child`. 
This only happens if you drag it down after half width of the `.child`, and this completely disappears if you drag it left onto the previous `.child` and go back to the normal position.

This is why the `#container` receives the drop event -- it's happening in the container!

In [my version](http://jsfiddle.net/U9k7d/2/) of your JSFiddle, one can reproduce the bug by moving a `.child` onto another `.child` and then downwards, until below the black margin. Notice that the parent (The black box) doesn't shrink even though it the child is outside.

This behaviour is partially fixed with higher versions of JQuery UI.

With [JQuery 2.0.2 and JQuery UI](http://jsfiddle.net/snugghash/kZ9JC/) 1.10.3, it's completely fixed. 
It's very  likely that this is a bug.

Comment: " it's happening in the container!" - did you inspect the DOM..? the item being appended to `.parent` hence it's not happening in `#container`. And **it's [not fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/YMnwU/7/)** in newer versions of jquery, (it's just harder to reproduce in `v1.10.3` since we're unable to drag much to bottom...)  yes, this is possibly a bug which is [reported here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/10113) and is open...

Comment: At first I thought I was talking about a different( yet causal) issue: that of the `.parent` not shrinking and the placeholder remaining visible when the `.child` was outside the parent (depending upon tolerance of course). 
After more testing, this _is_ the issue, yet I wasn't able to reproduce it on [JQ 2.0.2 and JQUI 1.10.3](http://jsfiddle.net/snugghash/kZ9JC/3/). I did however reproduce it with JQ 1.x.
_Am I wrong here? Is the container receiving the event when the pointer(half-height in the new JSFiddle) is **inside** the parent? Humour me and test it out..._

Comment: in 1.10.3 it's hard to reproduce but still occurs rarely. it's already tested even with 1.11 and query-ui team has marked it as an open bug, which i mentioned in my previous comment.